# Plot igraph with Fixed Vertex Locations AND with Non-Overlapping Edges

Tags: r, plot, igraph, dagitty

I want to plot my igraph graph with fixed vertex locations and have the edges automatically plotted around the vertices and not on top of each other rather than underneath other vertices and overlapping with each other.

Unfortunately, when I try to use a function like autocurve.edges(g) to curve the arrows automatically, it gives all 0s as the suggested curvature. PLUS, i don't even really want curvature, what I actually want is for all the arrows to be clearly visible and not overlapping with each other nor overlapping with one another.
My code:

```
d<-dagitty::dagitty("dag {
  t1.0
  t1.3
  t2.0
  t3.0
  t4.0
  t4.3
  t1.0 -> t2.0 [beta=1]
  t1.0 -> t3.0 [beta=2]
  t1.0 -> t4.0 [beta=3]
  t1.3 <-> t4.3 [beta=4]
  t2.0 -> t4.3 [beta=5]
  t2.0 -> t3.2 [beta=6]
  t3.0 -> t4.0 [beta=7]
}")
g<-SEMgraph::dagitty2graph(d)
b<-c("1", "2", "3", "6", "5", "7","4")
g_vertex_coords<-matrix(c(
1,    0,
2,    0,
3,    0,
1,    3,
4,    3,
4,    0,
3,    2
),byrow=TRUE,ncol=2)
ae<-autocurve.edges(g)
plot(g, edge.label=b,layout=g_vertex_coords,edge.curved=ae)
```

The above code yields this graph:

[image: bad graph]

Instead I want something with no overlap that looks more like this:

[image: example of good graph]
Which for now I'm manually achieving with:

```
ae<-c(0,.5,.5,0,0,0,0,0)
plot(g, edge.label=b,layout=g_vertex_coords,edge.curved=ae)
```

Again, I don't really need any specific curvature, I just can't figure out how to automatically get edges not to overlap the nodes or place the edge labels not all on top of each other, etc.  I've also tried using the ggdag, qgraph, with little success.  By the way in case it's relevant, the logic of my fixed location nodes is because each node is actually two separate variables combined, a trait and a time.  So I want the times to be what orders the nodes, and then I decided to put the same traits in the same column, but I guess that's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find you get nicer cosmetic results with `ggraph`, using manual layout to specify the x, y positions, and `geom_edge_arc` to clearly separate the edges:

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

ggraph(g, layout = 'manual', x = g_vertex_coords[,1], y = g_vertex_coords[,2]) +
  geom_edge_arc(aes(label = seq_along(from)),
                strength = c(0, 0.4, -0.2, 0, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1),
                arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(3, 'mm'),
                              type = 'closed'), end_cap = circle(7, 'mm'),
                start_cap = circle(7, 'mm'),
                color = 'gray50',
                label_dodge = unit(2, 'mm'), vjust = -1) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(r = 0.15), fill = '#ffe0a0', color = 'orange4') +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name)) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_graph()
```

[image]

If you don't want to have to manually set the curve for each edge, set a single low-valued `strength` to the arc but keep the rest of the code the same:

```r
ggraph(g, layout = 'manual', x = g_vertex_coords[,1], y = g_vertex_coords[,2]) +
  geom_edge_arc(aes(label = seq_along(from)),
                strength = 0.25,
                arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(3, 'mm'),
                              type = 'closed'), end_cap = circle(7, 'mm'),
                start_cap = circle(7, 'mm'),
                color = 'gray50',
                label_dodge = unit(2, 'mm'), vjust = -1) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(r = 0.15), fill = '#ffe0a0', color = 'orange4') +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name)) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_graph()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To plot with axes, you can try:

```r
ggraph(g, layout = 'manual', x = g_vertex_coords[,1], y = g_vertex_coords[,2]) +
  geom_edge_arc(aes(label = seq_along(from)),
                strength = c(0, 0.4, -0.2, 0, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1),
                arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(3, 'mm'),
                              type = 'closed'), end_cap = circle(7, 'mm'),
                start_cap = circle(7, 'mm'),
                color = 'gray50',
                label_dodge = unit(2, 'mm'), vjust = -1) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(r = 0.15), fill = '#ffe0a0', color = '#60401080',
                   size = 0.8) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name)) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, this worked well. Follow Up: is there a way i can make the manual layout compatible with axes?  Currently when I try stuff like `coord_equal(ylim = c(-1,4),clip="off") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,3), breaks=c(0,1,2,3))` the top circles get cut in half, and bottom circles have giant white diamonds go on top of them. i think it's because when i manually lay out the plot i can no longer add axes or something,  and the manual layout feature doesn't seem to have arbitrary axis control.   also graphics::axis(2,outer=TRUE) has dimensions that don't match the inside plot.

Comment: UPDATE: Fixed x-axis, just use annotate(), and probably that'll work for y axis too :) `annotate("text", x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = -0.5, label = c("A", "B", "C", "D")) +`

Comment: @AFriendlyFish it's very easy to add axes simply by changing the `theme` - see my edit.

Comment: ThkUagain.Iwant to submit this code toCRAN, and in the meanwhile passCMDcheck().  To that end I've been adding the `package::` syntax in front of every package.  But I can't figure out where to put the `tidygraph::` line in order to specify it's use.  I am not actually getting any warnings or errors now, but I'm also not using `tidygraph::` anywhere in the code.  You can see my latest, most updated code in this now solved other question I wrote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77377095/size-to-linewidth-ggplot2-upgrade-not-working-for-text-in-annotate?noredirect=1#comment136411826_77377095

Comment: According to "Access to tidygraph algorithms in ggraph code" in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggraph/vignettes/tidygraph.html  access is automatic but because i only need the package for one plot i just want to suggest the package and put a `if (requireNamespace("tidygraph", quietly = TRUE)){` wrapper around the code.  But how do I know if this a reliable solution.  It seems correct and like I've answered my own question.  But I don't feel confident that i know what im doing. thank you.