# size to linewidth, ggplot2 upgrade not working for text in annotate()

Tags: r, ggplot2, devtools, ggraph

EDIT/UPDATE:
Solved.  See comments for answer.

*************Original Below Line*************_________________________________________________________________
Two questions, first, I'm trying to upgrade my ggplot2 plotting code to use `linewidth` instead of `size` to display text with `annotate()` and second I'm using get('') workaround for R CMD's check() as I develop my package, but people don't seem to think it's a good idea, so I want a second opinion.

Q1.
Currently, when I run this code:

```
covarianceGraph<-dagitty::dagitty("dag {
  t1.0
  t1.3
  t2.0
  t3.0
  t4.0
  t4.3
  t1.0 -> t2.0 [beta=\"0.12\"]
  t1.0 -> t3.0 [beta=\"0.13\"]
  t1.0 -> t4.0 [beta=\"0.14\"]
  t1.3 <-> t4.3 [beta=\"0.41\"]
  t2.0 -> t4.3 [beta=\"0.24\"]
  t3.0 -> t4.0 [beta=\"0.34\"]
}")
g<-SEMgraph::dagitty2graph(covarianceGraph)
x_reordered<-c(1,2,3,1,4,4);  y_reordered<-c(0,0,0,3,3,0)
g_vertex_coords<-matrix(c(x_reordered,y_reordered),byrow=FALSE,ncol=2)
x_range<-3;  x_center<-2.5;  xAxisYIntercept<- -0.272727272727273
xLAbelYIntercept<- -0.428571428571429;  yLineXIntercept<-0.75
yLabelsXIntercept<-0.666666666666667;  ytitleXIntercept<-0.4
titleYIntercept<-3.78;  titleXIntercept<-0.0322580645161291
yLabels<-c("0-","1-","2-","3-")
yMax<-3;  yMin<-0;  y_range<- yMax-yMin;  y_center<-y_range/2
yStart<-ceiling(yMin);  yEnd<-floor(yMax)
edgeLabels<-c("0.12","0.13","0.14","0.24","0.34","0.41","")
Curv<-c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,-0.3)
varianceVector<-c(t1=2,t2=1,t3=1,t4=2)
print((ggraph::ggraph(g, layout = 'manual', x = g_vertex_coords[,1], y = g_vertex_coords[,2]) +
         ggraph::geom_edge_arc(ggplot2::aes(label = edgeLabels),
                   strength = Curv,
                   arrow = ggplot2::arrow(angle = 30, length = ggplot2::unit(3, 'mm'),
                                          type = 'closed'), end_cap = ggraph::circle(7, 'mm'),
                   start_cap = ggraph::circle(7, 'mm'),
                   color = 'gray50',
                   label_dodge = ggplot2::unit(2, 'mm'), vjust = -1) +
         ggraph::geom_node_circle(ggplot2::aes(r = 0.15), fill = '#ffe0a0', color = 'orange4') +
         ggraph::geom_node_text(ggplot2::aes(label=get('name'))) +
         ggplot2::coord_equal() +
         # title
         ggplot2::annotate("text", x=titleXIntercept, y=titleYIntercept, label ="Relationships",size=7,hjust=0) +
         # Y Axis
         ggplot2::annotate("text", x=ytitleXIntercept, y=y_center, label ="Total Temporal Delay",size=6,angle = 90) +
         ggplot2::annotate("segment", x = yLineXIntercept, xend = yLineXIntercept, y = yMin, yend = yMax, color="black")+
         ggplot2::annotate("text", x = yLabelsXIntercept, y = yStart:yEnd, label = yLabels,size=6) +
         # X Axis
         ggplot2::annotate("text", x = 1:length(varianceVector), y = xAxisYIntercept, label = names(varianceVector)) +
         ggplot2::annotate("text", x=x_center,y=xLAbelYIntercept,label="Traits", size=6) +
         ggraph::theme_graph(plot_margin = ggplot2::margin(0, 0, 0, 0))))
```

I get

```
Using the `size` aesthetic in this geom was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
ℹ Please use `linewidth` in the `default_aes` field and elsewhere instead.
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
```

And when I run `check()`, I get:

```
 ══ Warnings ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
── Warning ('test-plotCovarianceGraph.R:14:3'): Must manually test graph inspection ──
Using the `size` aesthetic in this geom was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
i Please use `linewidth` in the `default_aes` field and elsewhere instead.
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─testthat::expect_silent(plotCovarianceGraph(d, v)) at test-plotCovarianceGraph.R:14:2
  2. │ └─testthat:::quasi_capture(enquo(object), NULL, evaluate_promise)
  3. │   ├─testthat (local) .capture(...)
  4. │   │ ├─withr::with_output_sink(...)
  5. │   │ │ └─base::force(code)
  6. │   │ ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  7. │   │ └─base::withVisible(code)
  8. │   └─rlang::eval_bare(quo_get_expr(.quo), quo_get_env(.quo))
  9. └─physh:::plotCovarianceGraph(d, v)
 10.   ├─base::print(...)
 11.   └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(...)
 12.     ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
 13.     ├─ggraph:::ggplot_build.ggraph(x)
 14.     ├─base::NextMethod()
 15.     └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 16.       └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
 17.         ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
 18.         │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
 19.         │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 20.         │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 21.         │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 22.         │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 23.         └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 24.           └─l$compute_geom_2(d)
 25.             └─ggplot2 (local) compute_geom_2(..., self = self)
 26.               └─self$geom$use_defaults(data, self$aes_params, modifiers)
 27.                 └─ggplot2 (local) use_defaults(..., self = self)
 28.                   └─ggplot2:::deprecate_soft0(...)
```

Q 2. 
I was getting this error: [How can I handle R CMD check "no visible binding for global variable" notes when my ggplot2 syntax is sensible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when) And it seems to be the answer at the very bottom with only a single upvote is the best solution, just use `get('')`.  But I'm suspicious that there's something wrong with it since it isn't upvoted, so any advice on that would be great. thank you.  Specifically, I'm already using it in the code above.

Q 1. 
I have tried every single possible combination of using `aes`, `default_aes`, etc. that i could imagine in all locations, inside annotate(), outside annotate(), I even tried not using any of them, and just replacing the word `size` with `linewidth` in my code, but I always get one type of error or another.  Just as a quick example, when I replace `size` with `linewidth` `ggplot2::annotate("text", x=titleXIntercept, y=titleYIntercept, label ="Relationships",linewidth=7,hjust=0) +` I get

```
Warning message:
In ggplot2::annotate("text", x = titleXIntercept, y = titleYIntercept,  :
  Ignoring unknown parameters: `linewidth`
```

And I don't remember all the other errors I got playing around with aes commands, but i think default_aes for example was also 'unknown'

Q 2. 
I tried get() and it worked.

Comment: I get the warning without any of the annotation layers, so it must be an issue with ggraph, no?

Comment: wow. you are right, but I don't use the word `size` anywhere else in the code that i can figure out. I'm at a total loss i guess.  it's not a high priority problem as i can probably still submit this to cran. thank you!  
Is this something that I should post on the ggraph github issues page just to let them know one of their functions isn't working perfectly, or would i need to do a lot more work to hunt down the specific problem so i can give a detailed analysis?

Comment: Actually, thinking more, now that I know what the error is I've discovered a partial solution, calling library("tidygraph") before running the code fixes the warning.  but i have no idea how to fix it for R CMD check() because i dont understand what is supposed to be imported from tidygraph in my project. like probably i put the tidygraph:: in front something right?

Comment: According to "Access to tidygraph algorithms in ggraph code" in cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggraph/vignettes/tidygraph.html access is automatic but because i only need the package for one plot i just want to suggest the package and put a if (requireNamespace("tidygraph", quietly = TRUE)){ wrapper around the code. But how do I know if this a reliable solution. It seems correct and like I've answered my own question. But I don't feel confident that i know what im doing. thank you.